# How to Update the Metadata of Documents and folders in SharePoint Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, csom

i have a csv containing metadata of documents and folders contained in a Document Library. i basically want to iterate through the library and wherever the filenames match i want to update the metadata of that specific folder or item.

i tried using PnP but it doesnt handle large libraries very well as i kept getting the threshold limit error, so i decided to try a different approach with csom

i tried a test script to update the "modified by" column for a specific item and nothing happened

```
$WebUrl = "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/jr/"
$library = "DocumentsLibrary"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl) 
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName, $credentials.Password)
$web = $context.Web
$lists = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($library)
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllitemsQuery(1000)
$results= $lists.GetItems($query)

$context.Load($lists)
$context.Load($results)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$metadatalisting = import-csv "C:\apps\metadata.csv"

foreach ($item in $metadatalisting){
        $itemfilename = $item.Name

        foreach($file in $results){
          # write-host $file["FileLeafRef"]
          if($file["FileLeafRef"] -eq $itemfilename){
            $file["Modified_x0020_By"] = 'i:0#.f|membership|john.doe@company.co.uk'
            $file["Modified_x0020_By"] = 'i:0#.f|membership|john.doe@company.co.uk'

          }


        }
 }
```

my library has over 20k items, i want to be able update the 20k items in the library.

Comment: You need to use the internal names of the columns: `Modified_x0020_By` is actually `Editor` etc. Not sure if you also need to resolve the LoginName you’re using to assign the value - or pass in the user ID rather than LoginName string. For the high number of items, you’ll need to do this in batches, both for retching the items you want to change, and with an ExecuteQuery after each batch of updates.

Comment: Also don’t forget to call `$file.Update()` for each item you’re updating. I suggest getting this working properly for a single item and then introducing the loop.